# Automorphisms of finite order in $Out(\widehat{F_2})$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

Let $\widehat{F_2}$ be the pro-$\ell$ completion of the free group of rank 2, where $\ell$ is some prime.

Every outer automorphism of $F_2$ induces an outer automorphism of $\widehat{F_2}$, hence an injection $Out(F_2)\rightarrow Out(\widehat{F_2})$.

Let $\alpha\in Out(\widehat{F_2})$ be an outer automorphism. Consider the three properties:

(A) $\alpha$ has finite order.

(B) $\alpha$ does NOT lie in the closure $\overline{Out(F_2)} $ in $Out(\widehat{F_2})$.

(C) $\alpha$ is of determinant 1 under the abelianization map $Out(\widehat{F_2})\rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ (does this map admit a section?)

Are there any outer automorphisms which satisfy properties $(A),(B),(C)$?

Are there any outer automorphisms which satisfy $(A)$ and $(B)$?

I'm trying to get a grip on the outer automorphisms of $Out(\widehat{F_2})$ which don't come from "limits" of outer automorphisms of $F_2$. These automorphisms seem very mysterious to me.

Comment: Have you thought about $\mathrm{Out}(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$?

Comment: @HJRW Certainly $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ has plenty of automorphisms of finite order not coming from $\mathbb{Z}$, but that's basically why I included (C). I'm not sure if there's a stronger connection between $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ and my situation..

Comment: If we're consistent with the notation, $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ denotes the pro-$\ell$-completion of $\mathbb{Z}$, which is $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$. Its automorphism group (as a topological group) is just $\mathbb{Z}_\ell^\times$.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: *THE FOLLOWING IS WRONG* (I'm not deleting because the comments at least are very useful)

So the answer to both questions seems to be Yes, at least for "most" odd primes $\ell$.

First, it's a fact that the map $Out(\widehat{F_2})\rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ is surjective (Proposition 4.5.4 (b) in Ribes/Zalesskii's book "Profinite Groups").

Second, note that torsion elements of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ have order 2,3,4, or 6, and so its closure, being a profinite group, necessarily an inverse limit of quotients of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, must have the same property.

Lastly, the group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)\subset GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ often has torsion of order not in $\{2,3,4,6\}$. For example, take any element $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_\ell$ such that $\alpha\notin\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is totally real, and such that $\alpha^2 < 4$. This is easy for $\ell\equiv \pm 1 (8)$, since you can just take $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$. If $\ell\equiv\pm 1(12)$, you can pick $\alpha = \sqrt{3}$. Perhaps a more detailed analysis can cover the other cases, though according to YCor it may very well be possible that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ *only* has torsion of order 2,3,4,6.

Anyway, assuming we have such an $\alpha$, the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + \alpha x + 1$ then has complex conjugate roots $\beta,\overline{\beta}$, and hence $|\beta| = |\overline{\beta}| = 1$. Since $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ is a CM-field, all elements of absolute value 1 are roots of unity, so any matrix in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ with characteristic polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + \alpha x + 1$ has finite order. Since $f(x)$ must also be the minimal polynomial of such a matrix and $\alpha\notin\mathbb{Q}$, we see that its order cannot be 2, 3, 4, or 6, and thus the preimage of such matrices in $Out(\widehat{F_2})$ cannot lie in $\overline{SL_2(\mathbb{Z})}$.

I'd still welcome any remarks or references either covering the other cases or just more generally pertaining to this question...

EDIT: As pointed out by Will Sawin, of course $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ contains the diagonal matrices with diagonal entries $\zeta_{\ell-1},\zeta_{\ell-1}^{-1}$, which of course have order $\ell-1$, so the answer to both questions is Yes for all $\ell \ge 11$.

Comment: I don't think $SL_2(\mathbf{Z}_2)$ has any element of finite order not in $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$.

Comment: @YCor hmm interesting you're probably right. I certainly can't prove otherwise... do you have a reference/justification?

Comment: Counting the cardinals of $SL_2(Z/2^nZ)$, which is $3.2^k$ for some $k=k(n)$, rules out all order except $2^k$ or $3.2^k$, so we have to exclude 8 and 12. So we have to see that no quadratic extension $L$ of $K=\mathbf{Q}_2$ contains a primitive 8th or 12th root of unity. Note that $i\notin K$. So $L=K[i]$. If $a+ib$ is a square root of $i$, then we see that $a^2=b^2$, so it is $a(1\pm i)$, and $a^2=1/2$. Since $K$ has no square roots of 2, contradiction. Also, if $a+ib$ is a primitive 12th root, then $a^2-b^2=1/2$ and $a^2+b^2=1$, so $2a^2=3/2$, but contradicts that 3 is not a square in $K$.

Comment: The argument with CN fields doesn't work. All $l-1$st roots of unity are in$\mathbb Z_l$ so you can use those.

Comment: @WillSawin Oh you mean use the diagonal matrix with entries $\zeta_{\ell-1}, \zeta_{\ell-1}^{-1}$? Hah of course. But why doesn't the argument with CM fields work?

Comment: You need $\alpha^2<4$ for every real place, which it's not obvious that you  can engineer. You can get the $\ella+1$st roots of unity in a quadrati extension of $\mathbb Z_\ell$ as elements of norm $1$, so $\ell=7$ should be fine as well.

Comment: If the element of $GL_2$ is diagonal, then the obvious lift to $Out(F)$ (even $Aut(F)$) is still finite order. But if you want to lift an arbitrary torsion element, you have to be more careful.

Comment: What is going on in the paragraph starting with "Second"? Since $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ is virtually free, so is its profinite completion, and thus it has no new torsion. But that very freedom gives it many quotients with many other orders of torsion, like $SL_2(\mathbb Z_\ell)$.

Comment: @BenWieland Ah of course you're right, my mistake. Do you have a reference that the profinite completion of a virtually free group has no new torsion?

Comment: Shatz's book has some discussion of free profinite groups. The key point is that the finite index subgroup of a profinite completion is the profinite completion of the corresponding finite index subgroup of the discrete group. That reduces to the free case. Also, an element of a profinite group is detected by the abelianization of a finite index subgroup. So if a profinite group has a torsion element, it would have a finite index subgroup with torsion abelianization. But by the key point, that subgroup is also the profinite completion of a free group, hence no.

Comment: @BenWieland I'm having some trouble understanding what you mean when you say "an element of a profinite group is detected by the abelianization of a finite index subgroup." Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: For every element $g$ of a profinite group $G$, there exists a finite index subgroup $H$ containing $g$ so that the image of $g$ in $H^{ab}$ is nontrivial... Indeed, if an element is not the identity, then there is some finite quotient $Q$ in which it is not the identity. The subgroup of $Q$ generated by the image of $g$ is an abelian group. Let $H$ be the inverse image of that subgroup, a finite index subgroup of $G$. This group is defined by the property that it maps to an abelian group not killing $g$, so it does not die in $H^{ab}$... If $g$ were torsion, then $H^{ab}$ would have torsion.

Comment: @BenWieland I'm sorry I must be missing something. What exactly is the statement you're claiming? Are you claiming that the profinite completion of a finitely generated residually finite virtually free group $G$ has no torsion that isn't already in $G$? Or are you saying that any torsion in $\hat{G} - G$ must have the same order as torsion in $G$? Either way, perhaps I'm being dumb but I don't understand how you're "reducing to the free case". I also don't understand how you're using "virtual freeness".  . .

Comment: @BenWieland Suppose a profinite group has a torsion element $g$, then $g$ must be contained in a finite index subgroup whose abelianization must have torsion (ie, is not free). I don't see the contradiction there...

Comment: Most of my comments were about the proof that the profinite completion of a free group is torsion-free. About virtually free groups, all I said is that they reduce to the free case. Here is a weaker statement: if a $G$ is virtually free, an extension $F\to G\to Q$, where $F$ is free and $Q$ is finite, then a torsion element of $\hat G$ has nontrivial image in $Q$. This does not rule out the possibility of torsion in $\hat G$ not conjugate into $F$, but the possibilities are uniformly bounded by $Q$, a finite group accessible before completion. In that sense it cannot be "new."

Answer (score 2):

If an automorphism fails (C), then obviously it satisfies (B). An (A)+(B) example easily extends from rank 1 to ranks 2: take a root of unity $\zeta$ in $\mathbb Z_p^\times$ that is not $\pm1$ (requiring $p\geqslant 5$). If the generators of the free group are $x$ and $y$, then there is an automorphism of the $p$-adic completion given by $x\mapsto \zeta x$ and $y\mapsto y$. It obviously has finite order, but it has nontrivial determinant, so it is not in the closure of $Out(F)$.

---

Define $SOut$ as the subgroup of $Out$ with determinant $1$. I believe that $SOut(F)$ is dense in $SOut(\hat F)$, so there is nothing satisfying (B)+(C), let alone all three conditions. I will not attempt to show that, but only that all torsion is conjugate into the closure, which is awfully close. Specifically, I will show that an $\ell$-Sylow subgroup is contained in the closure; and I will suggest that there is no $p$-torsion ($p\geqslant 5$). (Added at last minute: that only covers prime-power torsion and does not show that torsion of order with multiple prime factors lifts from $SL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ to $SOut(\hat F)$, let alone to the closure of $SOut(F)$.) The key point is that $\hat F$ is a pro-p-group and thus pro-nilpotent. That makes it much easier to analyze than if it were, say, the 2,3-completion and pro-soluble, let alone the full completion with simple composition factors. The length $n$ nilpotent quotient of a group is a characteristic quotient, so an automorphism of a group induces a automorphism of its length $n$ nilpotent quotient. The group of automorphisms of a pro-nilpotent group is the inverse limit of the automorphism groups of the length $n$ quotients. (The transition maps in this inverse limit need not be surjective, but are in the free case, as indicated below.)

The automorphism group of a nilpotent group is easy to understand. If $G_n$ is a length $n$ nilpotent group, $G_{n-1}$ its maximal length $n-1$ quotient and $Z$ the kernel, then the kernel of $Aut(G_n)\to Aut(G_{n-1})$ consists of automorphisms that differ from the identity by shearing into the kernel: $\phi$ so that $\phi(g)g^{-1}\in Z$. Using the centrality of $Z$, the map $g\mapsto \phi(g)g^{-1}$ is a homomorphism $G_n\to Z$. A useful observation is $\phi(g)g^{-1}=g^{-1}\phi(g)$. The kernel is isomorphic to to the group of homomorphisms $G_n^{ab}\to Z$. $Aut(G_n)$ need not surject to $Aut(G_{n-1})$, but a similar analysis shows that if an automorphism of $G_{n-1}$ lifts to an endomorphism of $G_n$, it has an inverse. By induction that yields a nice clean statement: an endomorphism of a nilpotent group is an automorphism if and only if the induced endomorphism of the abelianization is an automorphism.

Applied to $\hat F$, this shows that the kernel $Aut(\hat F)\to GL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ is a torsion-free pro-$p$ group. Also, the map is surjective because freeness makes it easy to lift endomorphisms, which are then automorphisms. (Similarly, it is easy to lift automorphisms of the length $n$ nilpotent quotient to endomorphisms of the free group, but it takes work to lift them to automorphisms, which is why I do not do it. That would imply that $SOut(F)$ is dense in $SOut(\hat F)$. That would answer your question, but the points about Sylow subgroups would still be interesting.)

Thus the kernel $Aut(\hat F)\to GL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ is built out of composition factors of the form $Hom(A,B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are composition factors of $\hat F$, so the kernel is a pro-$p$ group. More careful consideration shows that $A$ and $B$ are torsion free, hence so the kernel. The kernel $Out(\hat F)\to GL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ is a quotient of the prior kernel by $\hat F$, so also a pro-$p$ group. I believe that directly applying an analogous stage-by-stage analysis shows that it is torsion-free. The kernel of $GL_2(\mathbb Z_p)\to GL_2(\mathbb F_p)$ is also a pro-$p$-group, torsion-free unless $p=2$. Extension by a $p$-group cannot change the prime-to-$p$ Sylow subgroups. For each $\ell$ prime to $p$, the $\ell$-Sylow subgroups of $Aut(\hat F)$, $Out(\hat F)$, $GL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$, and $GL_2(\mathbb F_p)$ are isomorphic by the quotient map. Similarly, the $\ell$-Sylow subgroups of $SAut(\hat F)$, $SOut(\hat F)$, $SL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$, and $SL_2(\mathbb F_p)$ are isomorphic. Since $SOut(F)=SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ surjects to $SL_2(\mathbb F_p)$, its closures in $SAut(\hat F)$, $SOut(\hat F)$, and $SL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ must contain full $\ell$-Sylow subgroups. In particular, all $\ell$-power torsion is conjugate into Sylow subgroups and thus into the closure of $SOut(F)$. And I claim that there is no $p$-power torsion (except for $p=2,3$, where all the torsion in $GL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ is conjugate into $GL_2(\mathbb Z)=Out(F)$).

All that applies to any rank free group ($Out(F)$ always surjects to $GL(\mathbb Z)$, but is no longer a isomorphic), except that there are more possibilities for $p$-power torsion in $GL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$. I think it is all conjugate into $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ (though I’m more sure about the fields $\mathbb Q_p$ and $\mathbb Q$). I don’t know how to tell if it lifts to $Out(\hat F)$, but if it does, it probably lifts to $Out(F)$. Anyhow, I claim without proof that $SOut(F)$ is dense in $SOut(\hat F)$.